# On button click number copy to dial screen, in list view

Tags: android

This is my program.

In this Android project there is one xml file in which a button is. Upon on-clicking of that the button, the dial screen would be displayed, which is what I want.

Here is code I tried:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle abc) {
    //super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    super.onCreate(abc);



    HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
    HashMap<String, String> item2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    HashMap<String, String> item3 = new HashMap<String, String>();


    item.put("name", "Taxi For Sure");
    item.put("number", "020 6060 1010");
    item.put("address", "For Pune City");

    item2.put("name", "OLA Cabs");
    item2.put("number", "020 3355 3355");
    item2.put("address", "For Pune City");

    item3.put("name", "Savaari Car");
    item3.put("number", "1800 108 1000");
    item3.put("address", "For Pune City");



    list.add(item);
    list.add(item2);
    list.add(item3);


    String[] columns = new String[]{"name", "number", "address"};
    int[] renderTo = new int[]{R.id.name, R.id.number, R.id.address};

    ListAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list, R.layout.taxi_row, columns, renderTo);

    setListAdapter(listAdapter);




public void onClick(View view) {

    int id = view.getId();
    int pos = (Integer) view.getTag();
    String number = list.get(pos).get("number");

    if (id == R.id.imageButton_call) {
        Intent callIntent = new Intent();
        callIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));

        startActivity(callIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your `onListItemClick(...)`?

Comment: Actually I want on button click not on list click

Comment: Please suggest me one code of OnClick method

Comment: there are 3 numbers(items) in the list, do you want one number to be forwarded to dial screen or all 
please be specific?

Comment: Yeah one number forwarded to dial screen....

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
try {
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+number));
                context.startActivity(callIntent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException activityException) {
                Toast.makeText(context, context.getString("Call has failed"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```

and make sure you have this permission in AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
btnPhone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View arg0) { 
                phone = editPhone.getText().toString(); 
                dail(); 
            } 
        });

public void dail() {   
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);          
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+phone));          
            startActivity(callIntent);  
   }
```